# Contact form 7 file upload not sending mail

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hello and thanks for reading this.

So my main problem is that i need to allow users to send an maximum 10mb file(doc / pdf). But if someone uploads a file bigger then 2 mb it fails to send the email, but the file is uploaded on server in wpcf7_uploads.

This is my setup

```
[file file-907 limit:10mb filetypes:doc|docx|pdf]
```

In file attachment

```
[file-907]
```

I also set up htacces to this

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value memory_limit 300M
php_value max_execution_time 259200
php_value max_input_time 259200
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1200
</IfModule>
```

And now i am out of ideas and in need of help.

Comment: Do you not need to change the items in your php.ini file to allow a higher post size?

Comment: No was just pointing that i tried that. That was seemed to be the common problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this deatil php.ini file:

```
post_max_size = 25M
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 25M
allow_url_fopen = On
user_agent="PHP"
default_socket_timeout = 60`
```